# Swift Package Manager, adding local dependencies

Tags: swift3, vapor, swift-package-manager

In a vapor project, my folder structure is the following:

```
Package.swift
Sources/
    -App/
    -Module1/
        -File1.swift
        -File2.swift
        -File3.swift
    -Module2/
        -File4.swift
        -File5.swift
        -File6.swift
```

After adding the 2 modules in each one of them, I edited the package.swift file to be the following:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "myapp",
    targets: [
        Target(name: "App", dependencies: ["Module1", "Module2"])
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Some external dependencies
    ],
    exclude: [
        // Excludes
    ]
)
```

Importing the 2 local modules works fine, yet when I try to use any functions / objects contained within them I get an "unresolved identifier error"

Anything I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need to declare `Module1` and `Module2` as targets.

```
targets: [
    Target(name: "App", dependencies: ["Module1", "Module2"]),
    Target(name: "Module1"),
    Target(name: "Module2")
],
```

Comment: And remember to expose any functions you want to use outside the module as "public"

Comment: @Makaronodentro you should edit that into the answer (and also mention open)

Comment: @Makaronodentro @Mark You actaully don't need to prefix your methods with `open` or `public` if you just prefix your import with @testable instead✌️